# Make blocks of 10 LEDs

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I want 10 red LEDs and next 10 white LEDs, and that repeated until I reach the end of the LED string.

This is the worst code, but it works.

What is the right way to do this? It must be very simple, but I can't figure it out

```
void Brabant() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i = i + 20) {
    if (i < NUM_LEDS) {
      leds[i] = CRGB::Red;
      leds[i + 1] = CRGB::Red;
      leds[i + 2] = CRGB::Red;
      leds[i + 3] = CRGB::Red;
      leds[i + 4] = CRGB::Red;
      leds[i + 5] = CRGB::Red;
      leds[i + 6] = CRGB::Red;
      leds[i + 7] = CRGB::Red;
      leds[i + 8] = CRGB::Red;
      leds[i + 9] = CRGB::Red;
      FastLED.show();
    }
  }
  for (int i = 10; i < NUM_LEDS; i = i + 20) {
    if (i < NUM_LEDS) {
      leds[i] = CRGB::White;
      leds[i + 1] = CRGB::White;
      leds[i + 2] = CRGB::White;
      leds[i + 3] = CRGB::White;
      leds[i + 4] = CRGB::White;
      leds[i + 5] = CRGB::White;
      leds[i + 6] = CRGB::White;
      leds[i + 7] = CRGB::White;
      leds[i + 8] = CRGB::White;
      leds[i + 9] = CRGB::White;
      FastLED.show();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace:

```
leds[i] = CRGB::White;
leds[i + 1] = CRGB::White;
leds[i + 2] = CRGB::White;
leds[i + 3] = CRGB::White;
leds[i + 4] = CRGB::White;
leds[i + 5] = CRGB::White;
leds[i + 6] = CRGB::White;
leds[i + 7] = CRGB::White;
leds[i + 8] = CRGB::White;
leds[i + 9] = CRGB::White;
```

with:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  leds[i + j] = CRGB::White;
}
```

Also, you need to change your `i < NUM_LEDS` into something safer; the loop after it could be going 10 LEDs beyond `i` and therefore beyond `NUM_LEDS`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this (still not "good looking but maybe a bit better)

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i = i + 20) {
    if (i < NUM_LEDS) {
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            leds[i+a] = CRGB::Red;
        }

        FastLED.show();
    }
}
for (int i = 10; i < NUM_LEDS; i = i + 20) {
    if (i < NUM_LEDS) {
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            leds[i+a] = CRGB::White;
        }
        FastLED.show();
    }
}
```

Make sure that leds[i+a] never gets bigger than the length of the leds array

Maybe something like this would also work (but not sure, I don't know the FastLED library)

```
for (int i = 0; i < (NUM_LEDS-20); i = i + 20) { //(NUM_LEDS-20) so that i+a+10 never gets bigger than NUM_LEDS
    if (i < NUM_LEDS) {
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            leds[i+a] = CRGB::Red;
            leds[i+a+10] = CRGB::White;
        }

        FastLED.show();
    }
}
```